# How to create a slideshow of subdirectories in windows 11

Tags: windows, slideshow

I'm trying to create a slideshow from all pictures located in a directory with many subdirectories.
The guides I found only work on windows 10, not 11

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can create a directory with hard links which takes very little space, and then point windows to that directory
The following script will find all jpg files and save their link in the target dir

save this script as script.bat:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cd <your\root\image\folder\>
set m=0
for /R %%f in (*.jpg /b) do (
echo !m!
mklink "<your\target\dir\!m!.jpg" "%%f"
 set /a m = !m!+1
 )
```

and run